# Is there any way on how we could detect and get the attributes (which do not have properties) from a user control tag?

Tags: asp.net, tags, user-controls, attributes

```
<uc1:UsercontrolTest ID="UsercontrolTest" runat="server" Hello="World"/>
```

You see, Hello is not a property of UsercontrolTest class, but we need to detect and get **that** attribute. Are we allowed to do that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Does the following not work?

```
UsercontrolTest.Attributes("Hello")
```

**EDIT:**

[UserControl.Attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.usercontrol.attributes.aspx)
: *Gets a collection of all attribute name and value pairs declared in the user control tag within the .aspx file.*

Comment: That is okay when we have the idea what the attributes are set on the tag. In my case, I know that the attribute is Hello, but what if another attribute (which I do not have any idea on what it is) is added? Thanks for the reply, by the way.

Comment: IF you don't know what the attribute is called, just inspect the list in `UserControl.Attributes` - it will contain the name of the attribute and the value it's set to

Comment: That's my problem actually. How can we inspect the UserControl.Attributes? The AttributeCollection does not have a List or Dictionary properties.